# Knockout : how to subscribe an observable array to a given propert of another one?

Tags: knockout.js, match, subscribe

Here is my viewmodel containing 2 observable arrays :

---

```
function VM() 
{
    var self = this;

    self.A = ko.observableArray([
    {"ID": 1, "Name": "one"}, 
    {"ID": 2, "Name": "two"}, 
    {"ID": 3, "Name": "three"}
    ]);

    self.B = ko.observableArray([
    {"ID": 1, "Name": "one", "Description":"description of One"},
    {"ID": 2, "Name": "twoB","Description":"description of two"}, 
    {"ID": 3, "Name": "three","Description":"description of three"}
   ]);
```

### };

What I need is ... when the value of the "Name" property changes in observableArray "B", it must update the "Name" property of observableArray "A".

Actually, I'm doing this :

```
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.B(), function (item) {                
        for (var index = 0; index < self.A().length; index++) {
            if (self.A()[index].ID == item.ID)
                if (self.A()[index].Name !== item.Name)
                    self.A()[index].Name = item.Name ; 
        }
    });
```

My question : Is it possible that A subscribes to B, so that when the "name" changes in B, A gets updated ? What is the best way ? Must I use "ko.computed" instead ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can define an `observable` variable for your data and then take advantage of  `computed observable’s evaluator`so computed observable function keeps track of its dependencies and you will be able to update the other array's observable.

Check this Example:   https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/107/

```
  var dataA = [{"ID": 1, "Name": "one"}, {"ID": 2, "Name": "two"}, {"ID": 3, "Name": "three"}];
  var dataB = [{"ID": 1, "Name": "one", "Description":"description of One"}, {"ID": 2, "Name": "twoB","Description":"description of two"}, {"ID": 3, "Name": "three","Description":"description of three"}];
  var AppViewModel = function(){
     var self = this;
     self.A = ko.observableArray([]);
     self.B = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.A($.map(dataA, function (item) {
            return new ItemViewModel (item,self);
      }));

      self.B($.map(dataB, function (item) {
        return new ItemViewModel (item,self);
      }));
    }

    var ItemViewModel = function(data,AppVM){
      var self = this;
      self.ID = ko.observable(data.ID);
      self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
      self.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
      self.UpdateA = ko.computed(function () {
        ko.utils.arrayFirst(AppVM.A(), function (item) {
          item.ID() === self.ID() ? item.Name(self.Name()) :"";
        });   
      }, self);
    }
    var VM = new AppViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(VM);
```

You wont see any difference between ArrayA and ArrayB's Name observable since computed function gets triggered as soon as its dependency is updated(You'll feel both Name of(A,B) are the same when the page is loading). You may want to consider using only one array instead of two since the ID and Name are identical and then you wont need to use a computed function anymore !!

Comment: Matt, thank you very much for your help. Indeed, when I use the only one array which contains all fields (Id, Name, Description), I can see the values synchronized ... But, I have an app where I have data coming from several tables from the database and I had to do this. I liked how you used $.map from Jquery to map each item array into an ItemViewModel  ... and also ko.utils.arrayFirst. Cheers !

Comment: Was the example helpful?

Comment: it works on jsfiddle, but in the context of my application, it doesn't. I get it done by a hack ... I triggered a click on Jquery UI dialog containing  B.name  ... and that updates A.name. Not professional, but otherwise I couldn't get that using knockout only.